# Importing Spreedsheet file from SAP GUI - VBA error 9 subscript out of range while using Workbooks.Close

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, sap-gui

I recorded in SAP GUI code below.

File EXPORT.XLSX saves at destination and new EXPORT.XLSX opens itself.

How do I save it at the destination without opening it straight away (for that I have different code)?

Or how do I close the EXPORT.XLSX. `Workbooks("filenamewithpath").close` generates:

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

```vb
Sub Pobierz_zle()
    If Not IsObject(SApplication) Then
       Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
       Set SApplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If
    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
       Set Connection = SApplication.Children(0)
    End If
    If Not IsObject(session) Then
       Set session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
       WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
       WScript.ConnectObject SApplication, "on"
    End If
    session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/n zle_stocklist"
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt[0]").Text = "3901"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt[0]").caretPosition = 4
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt[1]").Text = "3182"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt[1]").caretPosition = 4
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt[3]").Text = "3500"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt[3]").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxt[3]").caretPosition = 4
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chk[0]").Selected = False
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chk[0]").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
    session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").pressToolbarContextButton "&MB_EXPORT"
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlCONTAINER_1/shellcont/shell").selectContextMenuItem "&XXL"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/cmb").SetFocus
    session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt[0]").Text = "T:\DEPT-TSCW\WL\Inwentaryzacja\TEMP\"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt[1]").Text = "EXPORT.XLSX"
    session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxt[1]").caretPosition = 11
    session.findById("wnd[1]").sendVKey 0

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
    ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbooks("export.xlsx").Close` should work.  Do not include the path.   However that won't work if the exported file opens in a different instance of Excel (which I think is what happens when exporting from SAP?).  If that's the case then maybe try the `GetObject` approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73409136/478884

Comment: Also similar question here https://answers.sap.com/questions/737136/sap-gui-74-patch-12---disallow-excel-auto-open.html with a `GetObject` solution.

Comment: Are you working with Citrix/similar perhaps?  and  T:  is a network drive shared by your local PC and the Citrix environment?

Comment: @wrbp no no I'm working in SAP environment (production p11) but we use our shared local server harddrives to share multiple data sheets through our factory.

Comment: Excel definitely opens the SAP export in a different instance..... sometimes.  It's a daily problem I have - sometime it opens and saves with no problem, other times when I tell my code to create a pivot table based on the data I find it's opened in a different instance (so have to manually close and reopen in the correct instance).

Comment: ok Hello Friends, Today I reviewed my code, and tried Your suggestions - but no luck. What I noticed is that VBA runs faster, and doesn't wait until exported file (in my case EXPORT.XLSX) will be saved and shows up. I was wondering what I can do to make my VBA code to detect - is there the file yet or not?